# Android webview doesn't execute javascript function in some mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview app everything was working very fine on `HUAWEI RNE-L22` and `iPhone` too. Till i try to run the app on `samsung SM-G530H` it not not executing my javascript function but on normal phone browser is working.

The below line of code will not

```
function alertFunction(message){
 alert(message);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    alertFunction("Welcome");
});
```

Only this works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Welcome");
});
```

I don't know if this from my android webview or the website am loading

Comment: We will need more details, like the Android version of the phones, the version of the SDK, etc...

Comment: Also, try debugging the Javascript using this method https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews You'll be able to see what are the errors returned by the webview.

Comment: @RomainIsnel Android Version 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Best to create JavascriptInterface :

mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mWebBridge, "Android");

in Bridge class:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void Alert(String msg) {
    //Custom Android Dialog
}
```

Comment: from js...  Android.Alert('welcome'),   this will work with all version,

Comment: Not only alert function am creating, i just you the alert for debug and for question

Comment: ok, basically is used console.log() in js, and get log msg on WebChromeClient for debugging.

Comment: Okay am trying to see if i can get it working, i never use it before